Getting a wrong output calculating whether a number is an Armstrong number
I was just trying out a code for finding whether a number is an Armstrong number or not. But it was getting the same output for all the inputs even it is a Armstrong number. So I used an online compiler and it worked.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int originalNum, num, lastDigit, digits, sum;

    /* Input number from user */
    printf("Enter any number to check Armstrong number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    sum = 0;
    originalNum = num;

    /* Calculate the number of digits in the input number */
    for (digits = 0; originalNum > 0; digits++) {
        originalNum /= 10;
    }

    originalNum = num;

    /* Compute the sum of the cubes of individual digits */
    while (originalNum > 0) {
        lastDigit = originalNum % 10;
        sum += pow(lastDigit, digits);
        originalNum /= 10;
    }

    /* Check if the sum equals the original number */
    if (sum == num) {
        printf("%d is an Armstrong number.\n", num);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not an Armstrong number.\n", num);
    }

    return 0;
}


Why do you ignore the return value of scanf()?

I originally made a mistake thinking an armstrong number is a number equal to the sum of the cubes of its digits (regardless of the number of digits). This was wrong. I corrected my answer below accordingly.

In this line:
sum += pow(lastDigit, digits);

You use pow which is a function for floating point values, not integers. See some more info here: Strange behaviour of the pow function.
Instead you should use an integer based exponantiation.
This post suggests an efficient way to do it with the following function:
int ipow(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        if (!exp)
            break;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}

And then:
sum += ipow(lastDigit, digits);

A side note:
you should check the return value from scanf (should be 1 in your case) to verify you got proper input.

This solution worked in my friend's pc but not for me :(

Are you sure ? It seems to work flawlessly in my environment. Maybe you can try to debug it. See: How to debug small programs. What is the smaller number that gives you the wrong result (so that I'll try to reproduce the problem) ?

I think I got a problem with my compiler cuz it worked with different system.

I don't understand. Can you give more info so that I'll try to help ? Also please write the smallest value for which you get the wrong result. I'd like to make sure I get the correct one in my environment.
